# Verify remote open source software

Tags: security, p2p

Trying to wrap my head around how this could be accomplished, not even sure it's really possible. In simple terms, if I write a piece of open source software that is going to interact with other instances of itself running elsewhere, is there a way to validate that the remote software hasn't been tampered with? When my trusted local software instance X reaches out to unverified instance Y, what can I do that prevents someone from simply tearing out actual validation code and just "returning true" in their version?

No matter how I come at this, it seems that a central source of trust is always required (like in certificate chains) and direct peer trust is not possible. Even with a remote source of trust I'm not sure how I could verify/validate that the peer behaves appropriately rather than just claiming it is.

This is just an academic or design question that I'm trying to resolve, I don't have a specific use case or implementation in place to provide examples with.

Comment: you can't as soon as software in user's hands - he could do whatever he wants and alter behavior in any way

Answer (score 0):

Don't verify the software, verify consistency of inputs and outputs.